# Cannot access to webserver on Fedora 17

Tags: apache-2.2, fedora

I have  strange problem...

I can not access to my webserver from other computers.

I can not even access from server itself if I use IP address different than 127.0.0.1, localhost, or 192.168.21.68 (ip address of network card).

Error I;m getting is :

> The requested URL could not be retrieved

BUT, I noticed that I can access to server from itself if I use lynx web browser(!).

My html page does not contains anything but simple text on it (no images or Flash).

I tried to disable firewall, but result is always the same.

Can you give me advice how to solve this?

**UPDATE:** result of netstat -lnp | grep 80 is:

```
[root@digital ~]# netstat -lnp | grep 80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3492/httpd          
tcp6       0      0 :::38015                :::*                    LISTEN      733/rpc.statd       
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     18084    1116/dbus-daemon     @/tmp/dbus-du7H0oKPGU
[root@digital ~]#
```

Comment: How are you trying to access your server (using its DNS name or using a public/private IP)? You need to be more specific in your description.

Comment: I'm trying to access to it with IP address

Comment: Can you ping this IP address? Can you access it locally from same machine? Can you access it locally from same subnet?

Comment: As I said, I can access to webserver without problem using Lynx. Yes, I can ping server from other machines. Also, I did not mention that I can access to server's services like Samba or NFS.

Comment: @user48058: Can you post the output of `netstat -lnp | grep 80`?

Comment: sure, i posted it in updated part of my original post, tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this one.

Problem was that in local network, where two PC's with same name (new box was one of them).

When I pluged off network cable from the other, everything started to work.

What I do not understand is why it did not worked, because IP address of new PC was unique (both local and global), and I was not able to access to it neither with IP nor the URL.

What to say, except - you learn every day something new...

Thank you all on your help.